# Can't hear sound in Java

Tags: java, javax.sound.midi

I'm trying to play a bit with `javax.sound.midi` and I have encountered a problem - I cannot hear the sound. I have soundbank installed btw. The code looks like that:

```
public class MainClass {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Synthesizer synth = null;

    try {
        synth = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
        synth.open();
    } catch (MidiUnavailableException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final MidiChannel[] mc = synth.getChannels();
    System.out.println(mc.length);

    Soundbank sB = synth.getDefaultSoundbank();
    Instrument[] i = sB.getInstruments();
    synth.loadInstrument(i[0]);
    mc[5].noteOn(60, 600);

    System.out.println("The SoundBank might be null - " + sB.equals(null));
    System.out.println("The Synthesizer is open - " + synth.isOpen());
    System.out.println(i[0]);
    System.out.println(mc[0]);


}

}
```

The result of System.out.println lines looks like that:

```
The SoundBank might be null - false 

The Synthesizer is open - true

Instrument: Piano 1      bank #0 preset #0

com.sun.media.sound.SoftChannelProxy@7d132f26
```

Any ideas why the sound is not played (I tried different instruments, different notes, velocities and midichannels - no effect)?

Comment: The speakers are switched off :D.

Comment: Nah -checked that first

Comment: try on a separate thread. Just a guess. 4

Comment: Ahh - this actually was the path to solution - everything works fine since I added Thread.sleep() after the noteOn